# Geometric node point distribution flickers when the base mesh is displaced

Tags: geometry-nodes

[image]

[image]

[image]

This is what I'm currently doing, when I use noise to drive the curvilinear motion, the points distributed on the grid have a weird rotation and flickering, how can I get rid of this rotation?

[Blender File](https://www.dropbox.com/s/mamagfy6ut47j2h/128_GN_PointScatter.blend?dl=0)

thanks for your help!

Comment: Hello ! Could you highlight exactly where the weird rotation happens ? Currently I didn't find the problem in your screenshots with your explanations. Cheers :)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I've added a gif to the question to show the problem more visually.

Comment: It's because the distribution of points depends on the underlying geometry. Since it changes, some faces get larger and some faces get smaller, so the whole distribution flickers. You can try to distribute your points on the base curve line, and then displace everything with noise

Comment: Thanks for your help, this completely answered my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Gorgious said, distribution of points depends on the underlying geometry. Since it changes, some faces get larger and some faces get smaller, so the whole distribution flickers. So the only way to get rid of flickering - is to distribute points on a stable geometry, and make offset at the end:

[image]

The problem that you will face is how to get curve coordinates after converting curve to mesh? To do this, use **capture attribute** node:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your demonstration, and it also accurately predicted the problems I would encounter, which made me understand the usage of **capture attributes**, thank you very much.

Comment: @HenDaSheng If this solved your problem, I invite you to check the grey tick in the top left of the answer, it gives the person who answered a few points and it archives the thread so it's easier to find later on. Cheers